# how to make employees submit timesheets?

Tags: selenium, automation, artificial-intelligence

In our organization, we need to fill the timesheets weekly once on Mondays.

How to do it?

1. Open a website
2. select the previous week value from a dropdown.
3. Fill the web table with the approximate time spent for each task listed in the table for the previous week.
4. Click on submit.

Employees often forget to do this.

Is there a way to automate it? The entire process?

please suggest if some thing can be done on selenium web driver.

Comment: If your Timesheet application runs in Browser; Then yes of course.

Comment: yes, it runs in browser. can you please specify the method of doing it.

Comment: are you aware of how selenium works?

Comment: If  not I recommend go through following tutorial to get basic knowledge of how to use selenium : http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

Comment: yes, I know how selenium works. But how do I make the program run once in a week at the scheduled time?

Comment: For that you'll need to make use of Jenkins CI; where you can schedule your run

Comment: ok thanks. if possible can you please describe the steps. As I am  not aware of Jenkins, I might have to explore a lot

Comment: Even I don't know much but look for a tutorial on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to below image install jenkins then click on new item shown in below image:
[image]

2.Then enter your project name and select free style project and then click on ok button as shown below:[image]

3. then select build periodically and enter pattern(0 10 * * 1) shown below:
   [image]

every mon script run at 10:00 AM